# RegExp Negative Lookbehind workaround for React Native?

Tags: regex, react-native

I am trying to split sentences with some exceptions to ignore cases like Mr. And Mrs. Etc... And add them to an array.

This worked in vanilla JS for me

```
/(?<!\sMrs)(?<!\sMr)(?<!\sSr)(\.\s)|(!\s)|(\?\s)/gm
```

Unfortunately React Native doesn't support the negative lookbehind.

Is there another way I can achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create exceptions in the following way:

```js
let str = "Hello Mr. Jackson. How are you doing today?"
let sentences = str.match(/(?:\b(?:Mrs?|Sr)\.\s|[^!?.])+[!?.]?/g).map(x => x.trim())
console.log(sentences)
```

The regex (see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/q4HIXP/1)) matches

- `(?:\b(?:Mrs?|Sr)\.\s|[^!?.])+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\b(?:Mrs?|Sr)\.\s` - `Mr`, `Mrs` or `Sr` as whole words followed with `.` and a whitespace char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^!?.]` - any single char other than `?`, `!` and `.`
- `[!?.]?` - an optional `!`, `?` or `.`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```js
let str = "Hello Mr. Jackson. How are you doing today?"

let sentences = str
    .replace(
      /(!”\s|\?”\s|\.”|!\)]s|\.\)\s|\?\)|!"\s|\."\s|\.\s|!\s|\?\s|[.?!])\s*/g,
      "$1|"
    )
    .split("|")

let arr = []

for (let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
  if (sentences[i].includes("Mr.") | sentences[i].includes("Mrs.")) {
    arr.push(sentences[i] + " " + sentences[i+1])
    i++
  } else {
    arr.push(sentences[i])
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

If anyone has a more efficient solution, let me know!