# Android "com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name"

Tags: regex, react-native

Android run app crashed on splash screen with error

```
15:48:19.359  E  Exception in native call from JS
                 com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
                 Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name
                 
                 no stack
                    ... 7 more
```

Works fine on IOS.

Tryed to delete app, rebuild app.

Answer (score 0):

Just find out that JSC in RN doesn't support lookbehind/lookahead regexp. Can't find it in doc but found a lot of opened issues/question

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29271
[RegExp Negative Lookbehind workaround for React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73710025/regexp-negative-lookbehind-workaround-for-react-native)
and so on...

So in my case I refactored regexp without lookahead and it works....

`url.match(/(?<=v2+)([^?#]*)/)?.[0]` replaced by `url.match(/v2(.[^?#]*)/)?.[1]`